# Using Cufon and @font-face together

Tags: javascript, css, html

I think this is time of using custom fonts in web widely! The best and easiest way to add custom fonts to your website is [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/). This is easy to use and really cross-browser. It even support IE5.5 !!! Anyway it force client to download a massive script for the font and also user can't use "find" and "zoom" functions in her browser properly. 
On the other hand @font-face is widely supported now days and it's more semantic. [Here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/04/05/lessons-on-font-face-from-the-f2e-summit/) they spoke about @font-face browser support and other issues.

My question is how to use @font-face and Cufon together and deliver custom fonts to more clients with the best performance. We should not load Cufon's custom scripts when we can load custom font via @font-face and Also we should not load custom font in client side when we prefer using cufon in targeted client. (Think we have system/browser that supports @font-face but we preffer using Cufon).

I'm asking you to write an script that based on @font-face support and other factors like developer prefers and so loads Cufon or custom font. [here](http://paulirish.com/2009/font-face-feature-detection/) is a great @font-face detector:

```
/*!
 * isFontFaceSupported - v0.9 - 12/19/2009
 * http://paulirish.com/2009/font-face-feature-detection/
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Paul Irish
 * MIT license
 */

var isFontFaceSupported = (function(){


    var fontret,
        fontfaceCheckDelay = 100;

        // IE supports EOT and has had EOT support since IE 5.
        // This is a proprietary standard (ATOW) and thus this off-spec,
        // proprietary test for it is acceptable. 
    if (!(!/*@cc_on@if(@_jscript_version>=5)!@end@*/0)) fontret = true;

    else {

    // Create variables for dedicated @font-face test
      var doc = document, docElement = doc.documentElement, 
          st  = doc.createElement('style'),
          spn = doc.createElement('span'),
          wid, nwid, body = doc.body,
          callback, isCallbackCalled;

      // The following is a font, only containing the - character. Thanks Ethan Dunham.
      st.textContent = "@font-face{font-family:testfont;src:url(data:font/opentype;base64,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)}";
      doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(st);


      spn.setAttribute('style','font:99px _,serif;position:absolute;visibility:hidden'); 

      if  (!body){
        body = docElement.appendChild(doc.createElement('fontface'));
      } 

      // the data-uri'd font only has the - character
      spn.innerHTML = '-------';
      spn.id        = 'fonttest';

      body.appendChild(spn);
      wid = spn.offsetWidth;

      spn.style.font = '99px testfont,_,serif';

      // needed for the CSSFontFaceRule false positives (ff3, chrome, op9)
      fontret = wid !== spn.offsetWidth;

      var delayedCheck = function(){
        if (isCallbackCalled) return;
        fontret = wid !== spn.offsetWidth;
        callback && (isCallbackCalled = true) && callback(fontret);
      }

      addEventListener('load',delayedCheck,false);
      setTimeout(delayedCheck,fontfaceCheckDelay);
    }

    function ret(){  return fontret || wid !== spn.offsetWidth; };

    // allow for a callback
    ret.ready = function(fn){
      (isCallbackCalled || fontret) ? fn(fontret) : (callback = fn);
    }  

    return ret;
})();
```

I want a function like this:

```
if(isFontFaceSupported()==true && weWantFontFaceHere==true){ 
//add @font-face to the CSS and prevent Cufon
}
else{
//use Cufon
}
```

My question is how to this part:

```
add @font-face to the CSS
```

Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has a function fontAvailable where you can check if the fontface font is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(!$.fontAvailable('FontFaceFontName')) {
        // Your Cufon Replace Code
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, good to know. But my question is how to prevent loading @font-face fonts.

Comment: I you have a list of the browser you want to serve fontface, you just don't load the @fontface font. You can do this with a browser detection in Javascript (navigator.userAgent).

Comment: The problem is I don't have access to CSS file with JavaScript and as soon as CSS file is read fonts start loading. Any idea?

Comment: Just force the font to a non @Font-face font. Like: `document.style.fontFamily = 'Arial';`

Answer (score 2):

Using http://yepnopejs.com/ + http://www.modernizr.com/ (I recommend using the custom builder at http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/2.0-beta/) you can test for @font-face compatibility, and conditionally load either a CSS file with the @font-face rules, or load Cufon. This will accomplish exactly what you're looking for.

Unfortunately Cufon doesn't work in IE when loaded asynchronously. But since it supports @font-face, you wouldn't need Cufon. See https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/issues/171 for more information.